# Google Maps API v3: Is there a callback or event listener after zoom changed?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The Google maps API v3 has a callback on map `zoom_changed` but that gets triggered before the zoom starts (when I click the zoom in/out button). The state of the map inside the callback function is the one before zooming, I want the one after the zoom.

Is there such a callback?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: The link was deleted.

It seems like a bug in the API.

What most people try to do is basically the following:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed',function (event) {
    // some handling code here
});
```

But that won't work as the event fires before the bounds change. What is suggested to do in this case is the following:

```
zoomChangeListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed',function (event) {
    zoomChangeBoundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map,'bounds_changed',function (event) {  
      console.log(map.get_bounds());
      google.maps.event.removeListener(zoomChangeBoundsListener);
    });
});
```

So now, after the `zoom_changed` event fires, we actually set another listener, this time for the `bounds_changed` event, so at the time of this event firing, we are sure that the bounds have changed.

Comment: The links says nothing. This is why one should never simply post a link but actually write an answer that is independent of other sites.

Comment: @cprogcr: What does that mean?

Comment: sorry guys, been banned for a year from SO, and couldn't edit. Content added now